# What phase of the RadGrid life cyle is best for setting its properties in code-behind?

Tags: telerik, radgrid

What phase of the RadGrid life cyle is best for setting its properties in code-behind?

I want to specify things like editmode, column structure etc.

I am considering the Init phase or Pre-Render phase but am not sure.

Comment: Could you please provide your requirement so we will try to provide solution accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

RadGrid inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView so the API and event sequence of RadGrid are quite similar to MS DataGrid/GridView.

If you are manipulating view state stick to Pre-Render if not use Init

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.init(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender(v=vs.110).aspx